# Quelle est l'origine du verbe « étrainer » en français du Québec ?

Tags: orthographe, québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes, homonymes

Je trouve (dans une seule source, au Wiktionnaire) le verbe [*étrainer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9trainer) « *(Québec) (Acadie)* User, utiliser » et ça ressemble à une généralisation de certains des sens d'*[étrenner](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9trenner) quelque chose* : « être le premier à l'utiliser » et « en faire usage pour la première fois ». Est-ce une coïncidence qu'il s'agisse d'homophones ?

> Toutes les occasions sont bonnes pour étrainer ma nouvelle tuque !

D'où provient le verbe *étrainer* en français du Québec ; s'agit-il d'une variante orthographique régionale du verbe *étrenner* associée aux deux sens évoqués ?

Comment: Tuque (TLFi) : Région. (Canada). Bonnet de laine à pompon et à bords roulés.

Comment: @LPH Le pompon n'est pas requis mais oui. On connaît le terme bonnet mais c'est surtout avec ... _de douche_ ; ou _de nuit_ comme dans les films, pour dormir.

Comment: [Des tuques et des châteaux](https://youtu.be/89CAY3gTWCo).

Comment: Il est curieux qu'Antidote ne dise rien de ce verbe. Je suis à Montréal et je ne l'ai jamais entendu ni lu quelque part. 
Voici une autre définition : Au Québec, utiliser, employer. 
Exemple : À force d'étrainer ces ciseaux, il va finir par les user.

Comment: https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/etrainer/

Comment: @Oreste Pour moi c'est courant à l'oral, mais c'est seulement après avoir vu un contenu qui parlait d'_étrenner_ que je me suis demandé et me suis posé la question. C'est bizarre que j'aie pensé savoir écrire le verbe dans ce cas. Je suis pas certain. Un truc que j'ai pas abordé c'est la prononciation, je diphtongue ça (_étrainer_) quasiment autant que _baleine_, mais pas avec _étrenner_.

Answer (score 2):

On dirait bien qu'il ne s'agit que d'une orthographe erronée qui a peut-être mieux réussi à s'implanter au Québec qu'ailleurs mais on rencontre en France aussi des tas d'*étrainer* et d'*étraîner* où le sens est manifestement strictement le même que celui d'étrenner.

> N'insistons pas sur l'emploi plutôt agaçant du futur et la présence étonnante de quelques coquilles (p. 46 ; « étraîner » pour « étrenner », p. 105 ; « serin » pour « serein »), et reconnaissons l'aisance et le naturel d'un style agréable et fort bien maîtrisé.

[Québec Français](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/qf/1996-n101-qf1377398/58648ac.pdf), p 11.

Comment: Peut-être que je vais jeter un coup d'oeil à une copie un moment donné et voir si l'auteur corrige [ça](https://www.erudit.org/en/journals/lq/1995-n80-lq1185039/38667ac/). Disons que le substantif je l'aurais écrit _étrenne_ mais le verbe je n'aurais jamais imaginé ! Donc c'est utilisé couramment pour le vêtement ou des objets que l'on vient d'acquérir et qu'on a pas ou peu utilisés ?

Comment: Il me semble qu'*étrennes* est toujours utilisé aujourd'hui au pluriel (les étrennes, c'est principalement une enveloppe contenant de l'argent donnée en cadeau aux enfants pour le jour de l'an). Quant au verbe, il signifie pour moi utiliser pour la première fois un objet, généralement neuf. On ne peut pas étrenner deux fois la même chose, comme on ne peut pas cueillir deux fois la même fleur...